# Problems Creating New Initiative with Rally JAVA Rest API 2.0

Tags: java, rest, object, addition, rally

I am using the following code snippet to try to create an Initiative in Rally (the values I am using for _ref I obtained while debugging).

```
public void createInitiative() {
    CreateRequest request = null;
    CreateResponse response = null;

    JsonObject jo = new JsonObject();

    String wsRef = "/workspace/11785043049";
    String prjRef = "/project/11785043139";

    jo.addProperty("Workspace",  wsRef);
    jo.addProperty("Project", prjRef);
    jo.addProperty("Name","api_create_initiative_01");
    jo.addProperty("Owner","/user/17085226946");
    jo.addProperty("_ref",  "/portfolioItem/initiative");
    jo.addProperty("_type", "portfolioItem/initiative");

    request = new CreateRequest("Initiative", jo);

    try {
        response = api.create(request);
        JsonElement je = response.getObject();
        System.out.println(je.getAsString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

The response is :
{"CreateResult": {"_rallyAPIMajor": "2", "_rallyAPIMinor": "0", "Errors": ["Not authorized to perform action: Invalid key"], "Warnings": ["It is no longer necessary to append \".js\" to WSAPI resources."]}}

I have no idea which `"key"` is invalid.
Also, not sure if I should be using "Initiative" or "PortfolioItem/Initiative" both fail

Comment: What version of the Rally Java REST JAR are you using, and what version of WSAPI have you configured for the rest client? If you are wanting to use WSAPI v2.0 with Rally Java REST, you need to be running rally-rest-api-2.0.jar or higher. rally-rest-api-1.*.jar won't work with WSAPI 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

The security token needed to be append to the url as specified in the docs when you find them.
I had cannibalized code from the rallyapi test program for api setup and the security token was not appending when performing a create.  Also my code snippet above had to be changed to create("PortfolioInitiative",jo) and the property "_type" was not needed

Comment: Appreciate the update. So are you not using the REST jar then? The reason I ask is that using the latest and greatest pre-built rally-rest-api jar, all of the security token handshaking is taken care of for you.